# does proxying a 3rd party script introduce XSS attacks?

Tags: javascript, security, proxy, xss

Trying to send 3rd party scripts over [an SSL](http://blog.cloudflare.com/56590463) or SPDY connection is a hot topic these days.

Does proxying scripts from 3rd parties change the origin and sandboxing of scripts in the browser and introduce the risk of a compromised 3rd party being an attack vector?

If so, how can this be avoided?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using 3rd party scripts is and has always been a security issue. Proxying does not change that.

Remember that all scripts run in the context of your page, regardless of their origin. That's why using CDNs for libraries is possible in the first place. If someone compromised ajax.googleapis.com for example, the world might be in a lot of trouble.

The only difference is that you'll bypass the [mixed content security warning](http://i.msdn.microsoft.com/dynimg/IC310970.gif) when proxying scripts from http hosts.

> If so, how can this be avoided?

Copy, don't proxy.